# How do I force the usual "default" formatting that pandas dataframes output to?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-styles

I'm using a jupyter like platform that has truly terrible visual capabilities and one of the annoying things is that when simply seeing a dataframe by having it be the last thing in a cell all the usual pandas formatting is gone if I turn it into a styler.

What I mean by that is:

- alternating rows white / grey
- hover over row gets me nothing instead of that blue highlighting
- numbers are aligned in weird ways

I want to use styler because it allows me to format numbers easily (ie things like `'{:,.0f}'` or `'{:.1%}'`.

Is there a way to force the formatting to match the "default" in some easy way? eg where is the default stored?

```
df # this works fine as an output


df.style # this loses all default formatting
```

Comment: do you know if your editor is missing anything it needs for it to detect a DataFrame table? At one time google colab refused to auto format a `Styler` since DataFrame HTML add the `dataframe` class in `<table class="dataframe">`, whereas Styler doesnt. You could try `df.style.set_table_attributes('class="dataframe"')` and see if it helps..

Comment: And just for clarity... DataFrames do not have default formatting. It is your browser or rendering engine that adds the default formatting. The output HTML from pandas is raw and basic (albeit the Styler can be fully custom made). This is why tables look differently in Colab and Jupyter and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some editors rely on CSS classes to apply their own browser specific styling.

At one time google colab refused to auto format a Styler since DataFrame HTML adds the dataframe class in `<table class="dataframe">`, whereas Styler doesnt.

Try using `df.style.set_table_attributes('class="dataframe"')`